# parse an xml file (with DOM parser) in android

Tags: android

I have an XML file /res/raw/myxml.xml

I want to parse it with DOM Parser

I used this [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)  but my problem how to read this XML file in local

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = mcontext.getResources(R.raw.myxml);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

I have an error in this line `Document doc = mcontext.getResources(R.raw.myxml);` in mcontext the error message is  `mcontext cannot be resolved`

I want to parse this document with DOM not with SAX

I try the SAX Parser but with it i have a problem with execution of an XPATH query, for this I changed the parser

Comment: It would be helpful to see the text of the error messages.

Comment: the error message is mcontext cannot be resolved

Comment: Thank you, too. You did 29 questions so far on StackOverflow and mostly you got an answer but you didn't chose any answer as the solution. You motivate programmers to answer your questions if you chose a correct answer since those persons will be rewarded with points that can be used for e. g. pushing up their own questions. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxml);
```

Use this, it worked for my code but I used this with `InputStream`. Maybe it also works for your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an XML file /res/raw/myxml.xml. I want to pase it with DOM Parser

Why? Put the XML in `res/xml/` and get at it via `getXml()` on a `Resources` object. For compiled XML resources, this will be about 10 times faster than SAX and probably 30-40 times faster than DOM. This will run faster and consume less battery life. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Resources/XML) demonstrating this.

> I have an error in this line Document doc = mcontext.getResources(R.raw.myxml); in mcontext the error message is mcontext cannot be resolved

That is because you do not have an `mcontext` variable or data member defined. Newcomers to Java should learn Java before trying to develop in Java for Android.